# n characters between words in regex

Tags: r, regex

I would like to match following pattern using regex (in R, version 3.3.1): word, anything up to 10 characters - word.

I have tried the following code: `"word1".{0,10}"word2"$`, and some other similar combinations but without success.

Here are some examples for output:

```
x <- c('word1 word2',           # TRUE
       'word1 bla word2',       # TRUE
       'word1 blablabla word2') # FALSE
```

etc

---

**EDIT:**
I tried all your suggestions but non of them work. I try to query some data from DATA API. In query part I have to write what do I want to GET. For example this works: query = list(q = paste0("\"", "SomeSurname", ".*", "SomeName", ".*", "\"", "~5", sep = ""))), but if I want to add constraint in the way that there could be maximum 10 arbitrary characters between name and surname it doesn't work: query = list(q = paste0("\"", prebivaliste[i,"prezime"], ".{0,5}", prebivaliste[i,"ime"],"\"", "~5", sep = "")))

Comment: Your [**regex works**](https://regex101.com/r/uR7jE8/1) - without the quotes and the anchor `$`, that is.

Comment: I don't know R but according to https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html `word1.{0,10}word2` should work.

Comment: @slim: Problem will be the `$` and the double quotes.

Comment: If you only want to match whole words, you need spaces or word boundaries: `grep("word1 .{0,10} word2", x)` or `grep("\\bword1\\b.{0,10}\\bword2\\b", x)`, where `x` is the vector containing the strings you want to search for matches. The former case will match partial words word1 has a prefix or word2 has a suffix.

Comment: r has passed regex in popularity I see

Comment: I tried all your suggestions but non of them work. I try to query some data from DATA API. In query part I have to write what do I want to GET. For example this works: `query = list(q = paste0("\"", "SomeSurname", ".*", "SomeName", ".*", "\"", "~5", sep = "")))`, but if I want to add constraint in the way that there could be maximum 10 arbitrary characters between name and surname it doesn't work: `query = list(q = paste0("\"", prebivaliste[i,"prezime"], ".{0,5}", prebivaliste[i,"ime"],"\"", "~5", sep = "")))`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should match what you're after:

```
(word1)(?:.){0,10}(word2)

(word1) - capture the literal text: "word1"
(?:.) - Set up non capturing group for any character
{0,10} - 0-10 times
(word2) - capture the literal text "word2"
```

---

```
grepl('(word1)(?:.){0,10}(word2)', x)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Assuming you wanted to capture any word instead of word1/word2 you could use `\\w` or `\\w+` to match

Live example: https://regex101.com/r/xJ3yZ2/1

Comment: I have tried  `query = list(q = paste0("\"", "(", noquote(word1), ")", "(?:.){0,10}", "(", noquote(word2) , ")", "\"", "~5", sep = "")))` but without succes

Comment: No need for capture groups.

Comment: Mislav -- What language is this and could you put something on ideone and I'll hammer away at it?

Comment: @Jota  There's no need for them, but generally I assume that the person wants to "capture" the words that they're after (and perhaps handle them programmatically by using [1] [2], rather than just making a regex that matches).   Based on the question, it seems likely that he wants to capture the words and disregard whatever comes in between them.

Comment: @Jota -- This seems to work without issues using rfiddle:  http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=acOKfRie (not matching longer than 10) vs http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=Pbsxf4cT matching up to 10.

Comment: No worries @Jota -- thanks for the assist :)   r isn't my favorite regex language so any help is appreciated.   Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is simple with this:

```
nchar(gsub('word1|word2','',string))<=10
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```